# How do I achieve the following result using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[image: Actual Extracted Data]

[image: Needed DATA format]

Need to achieve the from picture at top to the picture at the bottom.

I tried many ways of pandas such as

```
pandas.melt
pandas.pivot
pandas.pivot_table
pandas.groupby
```

Still couldnt achieve it

What could be the way t achieve

Comment: This is an issue to solve on input, not after you've stuffed the values into an unstructured column.

Answer (score 3):

Even if this sort of task isn't exactly what makes pandas shine, it does make it fairly easy to solve your problem by passing to the underlying NumPy array and reshaping the data to fit a data frame:

```
In [13]: data = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', header=None).values.reshape(4, 4)

In [14]: pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
Out[14]:
  Rollno Name Class Marks
0      1    A    10    95
1      2    B    10    86
2      3    C    10    90
```

Do be aware that the resulting columns have dtype `object` though.

Comment: i have an error while implementing the code saying - install xlrd

Comment: and as my file is in .csv format is there an alternative

Comment: As you have tried using `melt` and `pivot_table`, presumably you've managed to read in your data with pandas already?

Comment: i have an actual data of array of 89 thereby resulting in a error - ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 89 into shape (0,4)

Comment: Then you would change that to fit the actual shape you need. However, 89 being a prime, you might find it difficult to fit 89 rows in a table.

Comment: It is unfortunately not clear to me what you want: It is impossible to convert 89 rows to a table with more than one column (or 89 columns), since 89 is a prime number.